# Log Message - Page Not Found: includes/database/sqlite/log/login

Tags: 7, debugging

When I check "**Recent Log Messages**", I keep finding a large number of "**Page Not Found**" errors with the message "**includes/database/sqlite/log/login**". 
I've checked the site and the directory does not exist.

My questions:

1. Should this directory exist? If so, how do I create it?
2. How do I determine what is calling for this directory?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely somebody trying an automated script to gain malicious access to your site. There's no action required.

Comment: To improve your answer, could you also answer the actual questions mentioned within bullet "1." and "2."?